# Database table cache_views_data is extreme large, what size is normal?

Tags: views, caching

I have a Drupal 7 site with ~70,000 nodes and ~500,000 terms. During some investigations for the cause of substantial performance problems, I found out that the database table cache_views_data is about 18 GB big.
Is this normal?

UPDATE: I am using time based and contend based ([Views content cache](https://drupal.org/project/views_content_cache)) caching.

Comment: Do you have views caching enabled on any of your views?

Comment: Yes, I am using time based and contend based (Views content cache) caching.

Comment: Do you have cron running?  It the size growing at a steady rate, or is it stable?

Comment: Yes I have cron running. I think the table is growing, but hard to say, how and when. I mean, I don't know if growing is caused by the growing number of nodes or by something else.

Comment: The table has ~8,534,796 entries, something smalls funny here, doesn't it?

Comment: Cache tends to grow big. Size does not indicate a problem. Lack of cleaning (cron runs?) and speed of growth could.

Comment: It seems that the table does not get flushed nieghter when the cron runs nor when I execute `drush cc all`...

Comment: Next time use @Mołot to let me know you replied. Now it looks like a bug in Views Content Cache. Try reporting it to their issue queue. It's minimally maintained but if you are right it's a major bug.

Answer (score 0):

There is no normal size, it depends on your site, but I think that there's some error because this table grows exponentially.

My site was down because the size of this table. In my case, with a few views & something like 1000 users this table was 29 Gigabits. I deleted it and then everything went back to normal.

I suggest you to keep an eye on the tables of your database, specifically this table.